# How to set a Mercurial VCS build trigger for TeamCity that ignores label operations

Tags: version-control, mercurial, build-process, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am trying to setup a build trigger for TeamCity using Mercurial as the VCS. Right now the trigger looks like:

```
+:/**
```

This trigger get fired when changesets are committed. However, I have TeamCity setup to tag each build in the VCS. The tagging process is firing the above build trigger so the build gets caught in a loop.

Can anyone suggest a VCS build trigger that will filter out the tagging process?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding the trigger pattern:

```
-:/.hgtags
```

filters out the .hgtags file from the build trigger. This is the file that gets modified when the source is tagged by TeamCity. When this file is excluded tagging operations will not fire the build trigger.

Comment: I've tried diffrent options/patterns to get rid of this problem. Actually this was the best solution at all! Thx

Comment: Actually this doesn't work! As the tag dialog says.. Note: checkout rules can only be set to directories, files are not supported

Comment: And I'd really like an answer on this too

Comment: Seems to work for me, I have the following rules  +:.
-:/.hgtags
-:comment=tag build:**

Comment: This no longer seems to work in 7.1. Has anyone found a workaround for that? It ignores the file, but not the revision itself.

Comment: I believe could ignore the revision by adding the same pattern to the checkout rules as well.

Answer (score 1):

Teamcity and the syntax above are foreign to me, but if you've got scripting capabilities you can check if a changeset is a tag-only changeset by doing something like this:

```
if [ "$(hg log -r tip --template '{files}')" = '.hgtags' ]; then
    echo tag only
else
    echo other stuff too
fi
```

Just swap out `tip` for whatever changeset you're about to act on, and change the echo statements to an `exit`, a `make`, or a `hg tag` as appropriate to either skip the build or just skip the creating of a new tag if the last changeset was only a tag.

Comment: Thanks Ry4an. Your script looking at the .hgtags file lead me to my solution of filtering out this file with a build trigger.