# Infinite builds when using VCS Labeling in TeamCity

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

We've just set up one of our projects in TeamCity (7.0 (21241)) to label our VCS when the build is successful.

This works fine in that we get Mercurial updated with the appropriate tag.  But, as this creates a new Mercurial revision, it's also causing the build to start again as TeamCity is detecting a change.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Apologies,  I've just found a post which seems to answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478297/how-to-set-a-mercurial-vcs-build-trigger-for-teamcity-that-ignores-label-operati  - just going to try it out now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We managed to fix this by setting:

Edit Checkout Rules (within TeamCity Version Control Settings) to:

+:.

-:/.hgtags

(note that the settings are on two seperate lines.)

VCS Labeling mode was set to 'Successful only'