# How to prevent the labeling of a build forcing a new build

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a Mercurial VCS build trigger for TeamCity that ignores label operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478297/how-to-set-a-mercurial-vcs-build-trigger-for-teamcity-that-ignores-label-operati)

I have my TeamCity project that uses a Mercurial VCS and labels the code if the build was successful.

The problem is that the act of labeling registers as a change and triggers another build.

How do I setup TeamCity to put down a label, but not trigger a build from just that label?  I am fairly new to TC and Hg, so I might be missing a key config value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1487622 is an answer from duplicate question

Comment: Addon: If TeamCity is v.7.1 - use Mercurial plugin from [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-10076)