# Ignore tags by specific user in TeamCity

Tags: version-control, mercurial, teamcity

TeamCity is currently configured to label successful branch builds, however, it's also configured to build when changes are committed to the branch.

Can the build configuration be configured to ignore changes made by the build agent user?

- TeamCity 8.0.2
- Mercurial via BitBucket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that usign [trigger rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules) like following:

```
+:.
-:user=commiter-vcs-name-to-skip:.hgtags
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Files output by your build agent can be:

1. Intermediate Files - *like `*.o` for compiled languages* - There is
   no point in keeping these so they should be in your ignore list
   rather than under your source version control.
2. Temorary files *- e.g. build agent working files -* These should be
   in your ignore list anyway.
3. Valid files that for one reason or another have to be altered
   temporarily by the build process, *e.g. if you have an automatic
   version number generation into a file that is normally showing the
   version as a test build,* these should be **reverted** by your build
   system at the end of *both successful and unsuccessful* builds so will
   not be different.
4. Output Files *- *like `*.exe` for compiled languages* -* These should
   be in your release management system **not** your source version
   control so should also be in your ignore list.

If all the above is set up there should be **nothing** to even consider checking in to your source control system at the end of a build so it doesn't become an issue.  Your release manager may wish to add the results of the build to the release management system after testing, etc.

You should be able to configure your build so that a change in .hgtags is **not** a reason for building again as was pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478297/how-to-set-a-mercurial-vcs-build-trigger-for-teamcity-that-ignores-label-operati?rq=1) by: 
Adding the trigger pattern:

```
-:/.hgtags
```

filters out the .hgtags file from the build trigger. This is the file that gets modified when the source is tagged by TeamCity. When this file is excluded tagging operations will not fire the build trigger.

Comment: He said that he has TeamCity label successful builds.  This will cause `.hgtags` to be changed and that is what is committed to the repository.

Comment: This would work well, but can the commits from a specific user be ignored?

Comment: I've not been able to determine what the user exclusion would be on a Branch Specification.